# I need help, styles do not load after deploying to Netlify and this error keeps appearing

Tags: node.js, gatsby, netlify

```
error (node:1384) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./public/" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/extract-files/package.json.

error (node:1406) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./public/" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/extract-files/package.json.

error (node:1400) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./public/" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/extract-files/package.json.

error (node:1412) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./public/" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/extract-files/package.json.
```

online link  https://dazzling-boyd-0942a0.netlify.app/

github link : https://github.com/douglasbpl/Projeto-Pokemon-Unite

Comment: I don't see any CSS in the source code. give me a second to look more closely.

Comment: I used styled componnent

Comment: styles seem to load just fine now?

Comment: They only load when I go on some route and go back to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

For me your styles worked when I changed the resolution to mobile (in dev tools) and back to Desktop. And now I can see your styles properly. At first glance it seems as if it's some CDN cache issue. Netlify had an option to 'clear cache' and 'redeploy' something like that a while ago (I looked in the pannel but could not find it). It seems it's some trivial issue related to the build process of gatsby or the caching at the CDN lvl. Maybe just try a re-deploy with a   new commit.

Comment: I tried and I wasn't successful